# How get handle of a global hook in usermode

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, keyboard-hook

I need the handle of a global hook that is created by explorer.exe by a module dll, this module creates a global hook WH_KEYBOARD_LL, I could now create my own WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, but I believe it is necessary to remove the old hook.

Example -

[image]

I would like to remove the first hook... i have 3 questions

1. it would be possible to remove in usermode?
2. making a global hook in SetWindowsHookEx I could get the handle?
3. UnhookWindowsHookEx work for what I want to do?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You cannot Unhook a Hook if you're not the application that set the hook. And in order to be able to set a global hook your exe needs to be located in `c:\program files` or `c:\program files(x86)` A 32 bit app can only hook 32 bit apps and a 64-bit app can only hook 64-bit apps. There is no need to remove the Explorer hook, you just need to follow the rules set up in MSDN.

Comment: See: http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/delphi_hook.htm

Comment: @Johan A hook will overwrite the other if the message type is the same, right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's a hook created by a game, I need to override it.

Comment: No, the hook **does not** get overwritten. However the last hook gets put first in the queue. If that hook decides not to allow other (global) hooks to run, then those hooks are effectively disabled. All this is very well documented in MSDN. And a great many questions on SetWindowsHookEx have been asked on SO. just google `SetWindowsHookEx` + `Stackoverflow` and you should get all the info you need.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the reply.